# Access Kafka installed on a minikube cluster on Windows 10

Tags: windows, kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube, strimzi

I'm trying to install Kafka with Strimzy on a local munikube cluster running on Windows 10, to test the impact of different parameters (especially the TLS configuration). Before moving to TLS, i'd simply like to connect to my cluster :)

Here is my yaml configuration :

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.3.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      external:
        type: nodeport
        tls: false
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      log.message.format.version: "2.3"
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 1Gi
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 2Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

For the listener, I firstly started with plain: {} but this only gives me services of type ClusterIP, not accessible from outside minikube (i really need to connect from outside).
I then moved to a listener of kind external.

You can fin below the configuration of the cluster:

```
kubectl get all -n kafka
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-cluster-entity-operator-9657c9d79-8hknc   3/3     Running   0          17m
pod/my-cluster-kafka-0                           2/2     Running   0          18m
pod/my-cluster-zookeeper-0                       2/2     Running   0          18m
pod/strimzi-cluster-operator-f77b7d544-hq5pq     1/1     Running   0          5h22m

NAME                                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/my-cluster-kafka-0                    NodePort    10.99.3.204      <none>        9094:30117/TCP               18m
service/my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap            ClusterIP   10.106.176.111   <none>        9091/TCP                     18m
service/my-cluster-kafka-brokers              ClusterIP   None             <none>        9091/TCP                     18m
service/my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap   NodePort    10.109.235.156   <none>        9094:32372/TCP               18m
service/my-cluster-zookeeper-client           ClusterIP   10.97.2.69       <none>        2181/TCP                     18m
service/my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes            ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   18m

NAME                                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/my-cluster-entity-operator   1/1     1            1           17m
deployment.apps/strimzi-cluster-operator     1/1     1            1           5h22m
```

The IP address of the minikube cluster is 192.168.49.2 (given by minikube ip)

For the while, is everything correct on my configuration ? I cannot connect on the cluster with a producer (i get a timeout error when i try to publish data).

I tried to connect to 192.168.49.2:32372 & 192.168.49.2:30117 and I always get the same timeout error. I also tryed to run

- *minikube service -n kafka my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap*

and

- *minikube service -n kafka my-cluster-kafka-0*

and i still get the same error.

What is wrong in what i'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to connect from CMD/powershell, you'll need to forward ports out of the hypervisor using netsh commands

Comment: I'm connecting from a java application (actually i've a java producer and a java consumer).

I never used netsh. Should I use it like this : netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=<some_port> connectaddress=<minikube_adress> connectport=32372 ?

And then use 127.0.0.1:<some_port> on my producer ?

Comment: try localhost:32372 0r 127.0.0.1:32372 , without doing additional changes

Comment: Some command like that, if you don't run the java code from WSL2 terminal, yes. You might have more luck containerizing the java applications and deploying to the cluster using the jkube maven plugin, for example. Your apps are meant to run in the cluster, anyway, right, not always external?

Comment: Actually yes my app will run inside the cluster. I wanted to make the exercise from outside the container to make sure i understand how minikube works. Thanks for the explanation, I don't have my code anymore with me, I'll try to finish this on monday. If I cannot, I'll deploy my app in the cluster.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I changed the type of the service to LoadBalancer and started "minikube tunnel".
Then I can access the cluster at 127.0.0.1:9094 (127.0.0.1 is the external IP of the minikube cluster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answser.
I changed the type of the service to LoadBalancer and started *minikube tunnel*

One other point, as I'm running this on windows, I noticed that if I run everything using powershell it works, if I used an other command line tool (like Moba) it does not work, I don't explain this.